# pyarrow cython wrapper Arrow:Table to pyarrow.Table failed due to undefined symbol

Tags: python, c++, cython, pyarrow

I simply pass a `pyarrow.Table` to `C++` `arrow::Table`, and then passed back to python. But failed with:

```
trade.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5arrow6Status8ToStringB5cxx11Ev
```

I have done some investigation and suspect that there is an issue of `pyarrow_wrap_table`, but don't know how to fix it. Your help would be very much apprecated!

Here are source files:

file: `table_func.h`

```cpp
#ifndef TABLE_FUNC_H
#define TABLE_FUNC_H
#include <vector>
#include <exception>
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/result.h>
#include <memory>

namespace MktData
{
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> aggregateTradeTable(const std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> &);
};
```

file: `table_func.cpp`

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> MktData::aggregateTradeTable(const std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> &trades)
{
    return trades;
}
```

file: `decl.pxd`

```py
# distutils: language = c++
from pyarrow.lib cimport *
cdef extern from "table_func.h" namespace "MktData":
    cdef shared_ptr[CTable] aggregateTradeTable(shared_ptr[CTable] &);
```

file: `trade.pyx`

```py
from libcpp cimport bool, vector, memory
from pyarrow.lib cimport *
from decl cimport aggregateTradeTable

def aggregate_trades(obj):
    cdef shared_ptr[CTable] trades = pyarrow_unwrap_table(obj)
    if trades.get() == NULL:
        raise TypeError("not an table")
    cdef shared_ptr[CTable] result = aggregateTradeTable(trades)
    if result.get() == NULL:
        raise TypeError("result incorrect")
    return pyarrow_wrap_table(result)
```

file: `setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import Extension, setup
import pyarrow as pa
import numpy as np

sourcefiles = ['trade.pyx', 'table_func.cpp']

extensions = [Extension("trade", sourcefiles)]

ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, gdb_debug=True)
for ext in ext_modules:
    ext.include_dirs.append(pa.get_include())
    ext.include_dirs.append(np.get_include())
    ext.libraries.extend(pa.get_libraries())
    ext.library_dirs.extend(pa.get_library_dirs())

setup(ext_modules=ext_modules, language="c++")
```

Answer (score 1):

problem solved by

file: setup.py

```py
...
for ext in ext_modules:
    ...
    ext.define_macros.append(("_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI", "0"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).